# inspect webview in phonegap developer app

Tags: cordova, webview, remote-debugging

If I deploy a phonegap app to my phone, I can inspect it via USB with a Chorme browser. However, with the phonegap developer app, the webview doesn't show in the list at chrome://inspect.

Is it possible to inspect the webview of a PhoneGap Developer App?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, use cordova weinre.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of weinre and it's very good. However, what's the reason why it doesn't work with Chrome remote debugging as any other webview?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extensive article on PhoneGap/Cordova debugging tools: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap .

It suggest the following list of debugging options depending on your scenario:

- Safari Remote Debugging (iOS)
- Chrome Remote Debugging (Android 4.4 and Chrome 30+)
- GapDebug
- Weinre
- WebKit's Remote Web Inspector
- jsHybugger

Comment: Chrome remote debugging is what I'm using at the moment. However, as per my question, it doesn't seem to work with the PhoneGap Developer App (http://app.phonegap.com/) and I was wondering why.

Comment: Late answer but that's the nature of StackOverflow: Chrome remote debugging is used to debug the pages within Chrome. But the PG dev app is not Chrome so it can't be accessed from the DevTools

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

But you will have to build your own version of the PGD app. Everything is explained here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer

First step is to clone the repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer.git
$ cd phonegap-app-developer/
$ npm install
```

It is then highly advisable to edit the list of plugins within **config.xml**, removing the plugins that you don't need, and adding those which you do need.

Finally, connect your Android device to the computer and run this command:

```
npm run phonegap -- run android
```

It should take a few minutes for your own copy of the PGD app to appear in the device and allow you to connect to your serving process. After that, the app should be debuggable using the Chrome DevTools as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#debugging-webviews).